# Replace different words in the same structure with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace, cpu-word

I found a solution here to replace single words with jQuery. The solution works for me in general but is it possible to short it a bit? Here's the Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.who').text(function(i, oldText) {
        return oldText === 'Dritter' ? 'Ich nehm die Nummer drei' : oldText;
    });
    $('.who').text(function(i, oldText) {
        return oldText === 'Fünfter' ? 'Ich nehm die Nummer 5' : oldText;
    });
    $('.groupheader').text(function(i, oldText) {
        return oldText === 'Sechster' ? 'i am number six' : oldText;
    });
});
```

For this `div` structure:

```
<div class="who">Erster</div>
<div class="who">Zweiter</div>
<div class="who">Dritter</div>
<div class="who">Vierter</div>
<div class="who">Fünfter</div>
<div class="who">Sechster</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten this by placing all the substitutions within an object, keyed by the text to be changed. You can then have a single line function which replaces the text with the value from the object, should one be found.

```
var substitutions = {
    'Dritter': 'Ich nehm die Nummer drei',
    'Fünfter': 'Ich nehm die Nummer 5',
    'Sechster': 'i am number six'
}

$('.who, .groupheader').text(function(i, oldText) {
    return substitutions[oldText] || oldText;
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/phsq3p02/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also shorten your code in this way with ternary operator.

**Code snippets:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.who,.groupheader').text(function(i, oldText) {
    return oldText === 'Dritter' ? 'Ich nehm die Nummer drei' : oldText === 'Fünfter' ? 'Ich nehm die Nummer 5' : oldText === 'Sechster' ? 'i am number six' : oldText;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="who">Erster</div>
<div class="who">Zweiter</div>
<div class="who">Dritter</div>
<div class="who">Vierter</div>
<div class="who">Fünfter</div>
<div class="who">Sechster</div>
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt2ay49h/1/)